# Different page from different functions

Tags: python, pygame

I'm trying to get pygame to display different pages based on functions called that's determined randomly. Ideally, when the right buttons are pressed, it'll move on to the next page automatically. When running this, the pygame window just stops responding. Any insight would be appreciated.

Running on Python 3x and pygame 1.9.5

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
import random
import keyboard

pygame.init()

display_width = 500
display_height = 500

black = (0,0,0)
white = (255,255,255)

gd = pygame.display.set_mode((display_width,display_height))

myfont = pygame.font.SysFont("Arial", 30)

def rw():
    gd.fill(white)
    letter = myfont.render("Press r and w",0,(black))
    gd.blit(letter,(100,100))
    pygame.display.flip()
    while True:
        try: 
            if keyboard.is_pressed('r+w'): 
                break
            else:
                pass
        except:
            break

def yk():
    gd.fill(white)
    letter = myfont.render("Press y and k",0,(black))
    gd.blit(letter,(100,100))
    pygame.display.flip()
    while True:
        try: 
            if keyboard.is_pressed('y+k'): 
                break
            else:
                pass
        except:
            break

def ctsh():
    gd.fill(white)
    letter = myfont.render("Press CTRL and Shift",0,(black))
    gd.blit(letter,(100,100))
    pygame.display.flip()
    while True:
        try: 
            if keyboard.is_pressed('ctrl+shift'): 
                break
            else:
                pass
        except:
            break

my_sample = random.sample(range(3), 3)

for i in my_sample:
    if my_sample[i] == 0:
        rw()

    if my_sample[i] == 1:
        yk()

    if my_sample[i] == 2:
        ctsh()

while True:
for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == QUIT:
        pygame.quit()
        quit()

pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: What is the `keyboard` module you're using? `pygame` doesn't have anything like that as far as I know. It's quite possible you're use if it is part of the problem (although I'm pretty certain not all of it after reading your code). Anyway, if it's not something expressly compatible with `pygame`, then it likely will conflict with`pygame`s own internal event processing which is how keyboard input should be handled when using it.

Comment: It's not pygame's module. I wrote the whole thing sans pygame and have been trying to tack on a gui on top of it......which in retrospect was pretty misguided.

Comment: As I said, you need to use pygame event processing to handle the keyboard—so you'll need to study that. In addition, try to get an understanding of how event processing in general works. The way your program is currently written, each one of those page functions is simply going to go into infinite loop, because event processing is either getting suspended or the `keyboard` module is conflicting something. With your current architecture, I think you're going to need to have an event processing loop inside of each one of them. See if you can get further along fixing at least some of things...

Comment: Search for event handling tutorials. Here's [a short introduction](http://programarcadegames.com/index.php?chapter=controllers_and_graphics#section_10). There's also [`pygame.key.get_pressed`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/key.html#pygame.key.get_pressed).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I mentioned in comments, the main part of the problem is your attempt to use something called the `keyboard` module with `pygame`, which generally requires you to use its own event-processing model to obtain input from the user.

Normally that wouldn't be too much of a problem, but in this case it's a little more difficult because of three things:

1. In your current program, you have each page function doing it's own keyboard handling.
2. The page functions have too much repetitive code.
3. Some the the keys you want to detect actually correspond to two different physical keys on standard keyboards, namely the <kbd>Shift</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> keys.

The following shows some methods of addressing these issues. It reduces the code repetition by what is called OOP ([object oriented programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming))—which in this case is by defining a generic `Page` class that can represent each of the pages you want to display along with methods containing the common code needed to handle them.

It deals with the dual key mapping by separating them from the regular keys so both physical keys they corresponds to can be detected. (This wouldn't be necessary if you restricted yourself to specifying the exact key, such as the left <kbd>Shift</kbd> key (`K_LSHIFT`) or the right <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key (`K_RCTRL`), instead of `KMOD_SHIFT` and `KMOD_CTRL` which can be used to designate either of pair—a list of all the key name constants is shown [here](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/key.html) in the `pygame` [documentation](http://www.pygame.org/docs/index.html).) In other words, the code makes it possible to specify `KMOD_CTRL` to mean **either one** of them, whereas passing `K_LCTRL` and `K_RCTRL` would mean pressing **both of them** at the same time is required.

To support event processing for the currently displayed `Page`, the main event processing loop checks whether the required key(s) are being pressed by calling the current page's `keys_pressed()` method to determine whether the required key(s) are all being pressed at once.

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
import random

DISPLAY_WIDTH, DISPLAY_HEIGHT = 500, 500
BLACK = 0, 0, 0
WHITE = 255, 255, 255
# Modifier keys which which correspomd to two different keys on keyboards.
DUAL_MODIFIERS = {KMOD_SHIFT, KMOD_CTRL, KMOD_ALT, KMOD_META}

class Page:
    def __init__(self, title, background, message, text_color, *keys):
        """ Save everything needed to show page and detect its keys. """
        self.title = title
        self.background = background
        self.message = message
        self.text_color = text_color

        # Create two lists and put each key into one or the other
        # depending on whether it's a "dual modifier".
        lists = (self.keys, self.dual_mods) = [], []
        for key in keys:
            lists[key in DUAL_MODIFIERS].append(key)

    def keys_pressed(self):
        """ Check whether all keys are all being pressed simultaneously. """
        pressed, mods = pygame.key.get_pressed(), pygame.key.get_mods()
        return (all(pressed[key] for key in self.keys) and
                all((mods & dual_mod) for dual_mod in self.dual_mods))

    def show(self, surface, font):
        pygame.display.set_caption(self.title)
        surface.fill(self.background)
        img = font.render(self.message, True, self.text_color)
        surface.blit(img, (100, 100))
        pygame.display.flip()


def main():
    pygame.init()

    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((DISPLAY_WIDTH, DISPLAY_HEIGHT))
    msg_font = pygame.font.SysFont("Arial", 30)

    # Create a list of Page instances.
    pages = [Page("RW Page", WHITE, "Press r and w", BLACK, K_r, K_w),
             Page("YK Page", WHITE, "Press y and k", BLACK, K_y, K_k),
             Page("CTSH Page", WHITE, "Press Ctrl and Shift", BLACK, KMOD_CTRL,
                  KMOD_SHIFT)]
    current_page = random.choice(pages)  # Start with random initial page.
    current_page.show(screen, msg_font)

    while True:  # Process events until terminated.
        event = pygame.event.poll()
        if event.type == QUIT:
            break
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:  # Keypress to quit?
                break
            elif current_page.keys_pressed():
                # Select a different page to display.
                new_page = current_page
                while new_page == current_page:
                    new_page = random.choice(pages)
                current_page = new_page
                current_page.show(screen, msg_font)

    pygame.quit()

# Run application.
main()
```

A closing comment:

I don't know exactly the purpose of your application, but think you should seriously reconsider the design of its human interface—needing to press multiple keys simultaneously is somewhat awkward and assigning a different combination of them to each page makes them hard to remember due to the lack of consistency (and is unnecessary especially since it always does the same thing of just switching to a different random page).